# OpenCL vector addition program

Tags: c, opencl

This is not a duplicate 
It is different from [OpenCL Vector add program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773749/opencl-vector-add-program).

My code outputs a bunch of zeroes cannot understand why that happens.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <CL/cl.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    //Max source size of the kernel string
    #define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)
    int main(void)
    {
    // Create the two input vectors
    int i;
    int LIST_SIZE;
    printf("Enter how many elements:");
    scanf("%d",&LIST_SIZE);
    int *A = (int*) malloc (sizeof (int) * LIST_SIZE);
    //Initialize the input vectors
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
    {
    A[i] = i; //if LIST_SIZE is very large
    }
    int *B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    //Initialize the input vectors
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
    {
    B[i] = i+10;
    }

    int *C = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    // Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    size_t source_size;
    fp = fopen("vectorCLKernel.cl", "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
    getchar();
    exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread( source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose( fp );
    // Get platform and device information
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1,&device_id,&ret_num_devices);
    // Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL,&ret);
    // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context,device_id,NULL, &ret);
    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector A, B and C
    cl_mem a_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), A, &ret);
    cl_mem b_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), B, &ret);
    cl_mem c_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), C, &ret);

    // Copy the lists A and B to their respective memory buffers
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, a_mem_obj, CL_TRUE,0,LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, b_mem_obj, CL_TRUE,0,LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), B, 0, NULL, NULL);
    // Create a program from the kernel source
    printf("%s\n",source_str);
    printf("%d\n",source_size);
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const
    char**)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    // Create the OpenCL kernel object
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "vector_add", &ret);
    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&a_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&b_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&c_mem_obj);
    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the array
    size_t global_item_size = LIST_SIZE;
    size_t local_item_size = 1;
    //Execute the kernel on the device
    cl_event event;
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
    &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    // Read the memory buffer C on the device to the local variable C
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, c_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,LIST_SIZE
    * sizeof(int), C, 0, NULL, NULL);
    // Display the result to the screen
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", A[i], B[i], C[i]);
    // Clean up
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(a_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(b_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(c_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    getchar();
    return 0;
    }
```

My kernel function is vectorCLKernel.cl

```
   __kernel void vector_add(__global int *A, __global int *B, __global int *C)
    {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
```

I have properly compiled the code but cannot understand why i am getting zeroes as output

0 + 10 = 0

1 + 11 = 0

2 + 12 = 0

3 + 13 = 0

4 + 14 = 0

Comment: Check every `ret` value for potential error. The answer why it is not working is very likely there.

Comment: Do you have a gpu? Does it support OpenCL? Did you install drivers properly? Do other OpenCL softwares work? Is `source_size` same as your code string + null character? Is it null-terminated? What is encoding of kernel file? Utf? Ansi? Ascii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you get in the habit of creating & using some C macro that checks the error from each and every OpenCL API call. It will make your life a lot easier.

2nd, the problem is that your calls to clCreateBuffer are invalid (all three). Notice:

```
clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), A, &ret);
```

You're providing a host_ptr argument. Documentation to clCreateBuffer says:

**CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR** if host_ptr is NULL and CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR or CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR are set in flags or **if host_ptr is not NULL but CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR or CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR are not set in flags.**

... just put NULL in there instead of A/B/C.